# Connect Bluetooth remote control with Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano, remote-control

For a project I need to connect a **Bluetooth Remote control** with an **Arduino Nano**.

On the Arduino-side I have an [HC-05-Bluetooth module](http://www.exp-tech.de/media/archive/gm/service/datasheet/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products.pdf). With the Android Application "Bluetooth Terminal" I can verify that the connection is ok, because I can send and receive Strings with an Android smartphone.

In the minimal example I send values from a sensor which is connected to my Arduino via bluetooth to the smartphone, which is working nice. So I guess the wiring is correct:

```c
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead( sensorPin );
  cm = 10650.08 * pow( sensorValue, -0.935 ) - 10;
  Serial.println( cm );
  softSerial.println(cm);
  delay( 500 );
}
```

Instead of sending sensor values, I need to connect said remote with the Arduino.

[image: Picture of the remote]

*(Picture shows the basic model of said remote control.)*

The remote control has the Bluetooth class `20258C` which means:

- Major Device Class: Peripheral
- Limited Discoverable Mode
- Audio
- Pointing device
- Remote control

**Remote Control Bluetooth  Specifications:**

- BT Device Name: YL-BTM3-xxxxxx
- Supplier ID and Product ID: 0x0A5C / 0x4503
- Class of Device: 0x20258C

My Question is: How can I pair those two devices? I can get the remote control into "Pairing mode", by pressing 2 Buttons. But how do I pair the Arduino-Bluetooth-module with this remote-control? Is it possible at all?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a comment, but..

For starters, you'll need to do the pairing from the Arduino with the HC-05 in master mode.

Check [this](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/bluetooth-hc05-how-to-pair-two-modules/) out.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already put it into Master mode and I also found some tutorials like the one you linked. But unfortunately my case is a little different: I do not know the mac-address of the remote control. (In the link the address is known and used to establish a connection). I just have no clue how to connect a Bluetooth device with "Limited Discoverable Mode" like this remote.

Comment: You'll have to scan for the "mac" address, that's described on the page I linked to. It is also possible that it is printed in the battery compartment of the remote, or as a last chance, on the pcb/bluetooth module. "Limited" just means that it is discoverable for 30 seconds.

Comment: Ah Ok. Thank you! I will try this and report

Comment: And if you pair using a PC, you should be able to see the "mac", or device address in the Control panel if you are using Windows or About this Mac on OS X, or "hcitool scan" on Linux

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the process and this answers my question. Unfortunately I have a follow-up question, which I have posted here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19517/hc-05-bluetooth-module-inq-command-doesnt-work