# HC-05 Bluetooth Module - INQ-Command doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano, remote-control

For a project I need to connect a Bluetooth Remote control with an Arduino Nano.

**The Problem**

I am trying to setup a connection to said Bluetooth remote Control. This device is visible! (I have confirmed it with a smartphone)

Here are the steps that I am trying to do with the Arduino and HC05 module:

```
AT <-- confirms, that Command Mode is running successfully
OK

AT+ROLE? <-- 1 For Bluetooth Master Mode
+ROLE:1
OK 

AT+CMODE? <-- 1 allows connecting to any BT address
+CMOD:1
OK

AT+INQM? <-- Show Inquiry access values
+INQM:1,1,48
OK

AT+INQ <-- Inquiry Bluetooth Device
```

After ~60 seconds, it just says "OK", but according to [this tutorial](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/bluetooth-hc05-how-to-pair-two-modules/)  or according to [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/Vr4cdpsoVEo?t=6m30s) it should display all Bluetooth-devices, that are ready to connect. 
The BT device is definately visible. (I tried multiple BT devices like smartphones and peripheral devices).

**Why is the inquiry not working? What is wrong here?**

**The circuit is exactly like in this picture:**

[image: circuit]

For setting up the Bluetooth-connection I wire the EN-Pin to +3,3V, which successfully activates **AT-Command-Mode** 
[According to this site](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-at-mode/), you can do it like that.

Here is my code, that I use, to communicate with the module. - It works good!

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX | TX
// Connect the HC-05 TX to Arduino pin 2 RX. 
// Connect the HC-05 RX to Arduino pin 3 TX through a voltage divider.
// 

char c = ' ';
int buf[64]; //buffer to store AT commands
int len = 0; //stores the length of the commands

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino is ready");
    delay(500);
    mySerial.begin(9600);  
    Serial.println("BlueTooth is ready");
}

void loop()
{

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    len = Serial.available(); //store number of bytes to read
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) //store all bytes into the buffer
    {
      buf[i] = Serial.read();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
      mySerial.write(buf[i]);
      Serial.write(buf[i]);
    }
  }


  if(mySerial.available())
  {
    len = mySerial.available();
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
      buf[i] = mySerial.read();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
      Serial.write(buf[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

[Here is a related question but the answer doesn't help.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180962/hc-05-bluetooth-atinq-command-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a factory reset of the device. That resolved the issue

```
AT+ORGL
AT+RESET
```

Another thing that is very important: The KEY-Pin (EV-Pin on some boards) must be HIGH (3Volts), during the INQ-command. If this PIN is not High, the inq-command will not work.

If you put 3V to this PIN and release it, you indeed are in AT-Command mode. But not all AT-commands work (e.g. the said at+inq command). If you want to enable all AT-commands the PIN **must remain** high.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example from the datasheet:

```
AT+INIT
AT+INQM=1,9,48  // max of 9 devices, timeout of 61 seconds
AT+INQ
```

And use this in your loop() instead:

```
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  while (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but this does not work, either. This command only changes the maximum devices, that can be found by the module. but since not a single one is found it doesn't help.